# Não consigo fazer funcionar pesquisa com eloquent e relacionamento!!! Laravel 5.5 e mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Eu estou fazendo uma pesquisa pegando uma parte de palavra e jogando numa pesquisa tipo `LIKE` para campos campos. Uso o `Eloquent` e relacionamentos, mas não traz os dados.

```
{
    $pesquisa   = $dataForm['pesquisa'];

    $atestados = Atestado::with([
        'colaborador' => function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
              $query->where('colaboradors.matricula', 'LIKE', "%{$pesquisa}%")
                    ->orWhere('colaboradors.nome', 'LIKE', "%{$pesquisa}%");
        },
        'cid' => function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
              $query->orWhere('cids.codigo', 'LIKE', "%{$pesquisa}%");
        },                    
        'situacao' => function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
              $query->orWhere('situacaos.descricao', 'LIKE', "%{$pesquisa}%");
        },                    
     ])
     ->orderBy('data_afastamento', 'desc')
     ->get();
}
```

Comment: Não deve estar satisfazendo por isso não retorna. Me diga não ta retornando o que? explica melhor, um resultado que deveria aparacer, algo do tipo ...

Comment: Virgílio, eu coloquei uma parte de matrícula no campo pesquisa que é 9-7

Comment: Vou colar aqui o dd do resultado. No caso trouxe todos os registros sendo que deveria trazer somente um que tem esta condição.

Comment: {Collection {#368 ▼
  #items: array:28 [▼
    0 => Atestado {#378 ▶}
    1 => Atestado {#379 ▶}
    2 => Atestado {#380 ▶}
    3 => Atestado {#381 ▶}
    4 => Atestado {#382 ▶}
    5 => Atestado {#383 ▶}
    6 => Atestado {#384 ▶}
    7 => Atestado {#385 ▶}
    8 => Atestado {#386 ▶}
    9 => Atestado {#387 ▶}
    10 => Atestado {#388 ▶}
    11 => Atestado {#389 ▶}
    12 => Atestado {#390 ▶}
    13 => Atestado {#391 ▶}
    14 => Atestado {#392 ▶}
  ]
}}

Comment: Só deveria trazer este.
{
     0 => Atestado {#378 ▼
      #relations: array:3 [▼
        "colaborador" => Colaborador {#377 ▼
          #fillable: array:7 [▶]
            "id" => 2
            "centrocusto_id" => 1
            "cargo_id" => 1
            "matricula" => "45839-7"
            "nome" => "João Carlos dos Santos"
          ]
        }
        "cid" => Cid {#367 ▶}
        "situacao" => Situacao {#371 ▶}
      ]
    
}

Deveria trazer somente este registro já que é a única matrícula que tem parte 9-7 e trouxe todos os registros.

Comment: Só deveria trazer  `0 => Atestado` não funciona assim, as relações de carga só aparecem quando a principal tem dados! talvez você precise fazer separado, eu ainda não entendi o proposito. tente explicar na sua pergunta que eu posso te ajudar

Comment: Bom,  é um sistema que cadastra atestados médicos. (absenteísmo). Então tenho uma tabela de atestado que tem dados (relacionamentos) com colaborador, cid (código de afastamento médico) e situacao (Status tipo afastado, trabalhando inss).
O filtro tem como objetivo pegar de um campo de pesquisa e passar para um select fazendo like da matricula, nome do colaborador. Esta tabela colaborador esta relacionada a tabela atestado.
EU pensei em fazer separado usando o join. Talvez eu tenha maior controle. O que você acha?

Comment: em vez do get usei o toSql() para ver o select e veio
{"select * from `atestados` order by `data_afastamento` desc"}
É como se o eloquent não pegasse a variável pesquisa e passasse o conteúdo para o select.
Esta parte não esta funcionando.
{
$pesquisa   = $dataForm['pesquisa'];

    $atestados = Atestado::with([
        'colaborador' => function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
              $query->where('colaboradors.matricula', 'LIKE', "%{$pesquisa}%")
                    ->orWhere('colaboradors.nome', 'LIKE', "%{$pesquisa}%");
        },
}

Comment: Se está querendo pegar todos os atestados?

Comment: Sim. Os atestado que correspondam a parte da matrícula ou nome do colaborador. Que vem do dataForm pesquisa como coloquei no comentário anterior. Só isso.

Comment: Vamos ver se eu entendi, você quer trazer somente os atestados conforme a pesquisa das relação, então a tecnica é outra, `$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();` é dessa forma

Comment: dessa forma olhe o link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence e você além disse pode trazer as relações

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) para conferir os dados da relação e com [with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) carregue os dados da relação entre as *entidades*, exemplo:

```
$pesquisa = $dataForm['pesquisa'];
$atestados = Atestado::with(['colaborador','cid','situacao'])
        ->whereHas('colaborador', function ($query) use ($pesquisa)
        { 
            $query->where('matricula', 'like', "%{$pesquisa}%"); 
        })
        ->whereHas('cid' => function ($query) use ($pesquisa) 
        {
            $query->where('cids.codigo', 'LIKE', "%{$pesquisa}%");
        })
        ->whereHas('situacao' => function ($query) use ($pesquisa) 
        {
            $query->where('situacaos.descricao', 'LIKE', "%{$pesquisa}%");
        })
        ->orderBy('data_afastamento', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)
- [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)